# Symfony Container Builder's `addObjectResource` Method

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

What does the Symfony Container Builder's `addObjectResource` method do?

That is -- I have some code in a [dependency injection extension](https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/bundles/extension.html) that looks like this.

```
$container->addObjectResource(DoctrineORMDriver::class);
```

If I track that code down, I [see the following](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/27d10a658dbf52157f7e0324bc9f1e5484f36097/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php#L295) (comments replace actual code)

```
public function addObjectResource($object)
{
    if ($this->trackResources) {
        // adds a bunch of stuff to ->classReflectors

        // calls ->fileExists for class and its interfaces

        // ultimatly the calling chain ends up adding stuff
        // to the ->resources property
    }
    return $this;
}
```

At this point I can restate my question a little better: What is a container builder resource, but I'm unclear on what's doing on.

Why would I, as someone writing a dependency inject extension, want to add a particular class as an object resource?  What extra functionality in the Symfony framework does this unlock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are any file that went into the configuration/build of the DI container. This is used in conjunction with the Config component to determine whether the cached container needs to be recompiled. Any change to a resource triggers a rebuild of the container cache.

Typically in the framework, the resources are your configuration files, but classes such as DI extensions that can modify the container also need to be registered, as a change to their code may alter how the container is ultimately wired.

So, your one-liner is declaring that the `DoctrineORMDriver` class is such a class, and needs to be checked when evaluating whether the container cache is fresh.

This is covered in [the Symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#dumping-the-configuration-for-performance).

Comment: Nice, thank you!  I'd been independently curious how Symfony managed that auto-cache clearing behavior -- two questions answered with one stone!